# Unable to copy docker image in JFrog Artifactory from one repo to a target repo

Tags: docker, artifactory

We have an Artifactory server to host our Docker images. I am trying to effectively re-tag one of my Docker images using the JFrog API. I know I could do this with a simple `docker tag` and `docker push`, but wanted to see how to do this more directly with the Artifactory API. Unfortunately I am running into a snag. Here's the API call I'm trying to make:

```
curl -X POST --user 'my@user.com:MyAPIKey' -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data \
  '{"targetRepo": "docker-local", "dockerRepository": "docker-local", "tag": "my/docker/image/original", "targetTag": "my/docker/image/new", "copy": true}' \
  https://www.myartifactoryserver.com/api/docker/docker-local/v2/promote
```

But this call returns the following error:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "'targetTag' tag value is invalid."
  } ]
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, especially since I *am* able to perform this same copy using the UI. How do I do it with the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the parameter values you are using for the dockerRepository, tag and targetTag parameters.
Here is an example of how to retag the image `hello-world:latest` (stored in the docker-local repository) as `hello-world:1.0` :

```
POST api/docker/docker-local/v2/promote

{
  "repository" : "docker-local", // Source Artifactory repository
  "dockerRepository" : "hello-world", // Source Docker repository
  "targetRepo" : "docker-local", // Target Artifactory repository
  "tag" : "latest", // Source tag name
  "targetTag" : "1.0" // Target tag name
}
```

Here is an example of a curl command for sending the above request:

```
curl -uuser:password -XPOST -H"content-type: application/json"  -d "{\"repository\" : \"docker-local\", \"dockerRepository\" : \"hello-world\", \"targetRepo\" : \"docker-local\", \"tag\" : \"latest\", \"targetTag\" : \"1.0\"}" https://myserver.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/docker/docker-local/v2/promote
```

Please notice both Artifactory and Docker use the term "repository", but each uses it in a different way.
A Docker repository is a hosted collection of tagged images that, together, create the file system for a container
A Docker registry is a host that stores Docker repositories
An Artifactory repository is a hosted collection of Docker repositories, effectively, a Docker registry in every way, and one that you can access transparently with the Docker client.

Answer (score 2):

Dror Bereznitsky's answer is spot on if you want to do simple re-tagging like

`demo-app:1.0.1`  `demo-app:latest`

However, if your tag is path-like, you can, using Artifactory terminology, promote an Image into a different "**Repository Path**" within the same "**Repository**" and keep the same "**Tag**" (version) in both places:

`com.example/stage/demo-app:1.0.1`  `com.example/release/demo-app:1.0.1`

To promote an Image from `stage` to `release` like this:

[image: Artifactory screenshot]

execute `POST` request with following body:

```
POST /api/docker/devops-docker-local/v2/promote

{
    "repository"             : "devops-docker-local",          // Source Repository
    "dockerRepository"       : "com.example/stage/demo-app",   // Source Path
    "tag"                    : "1.0.1",                        // Source Tag

    "targetRepo"             : "devops-docker-local",          // Target Repository
    "targetDockerRepository" : "com.example/release/demo-app", // Target Path
    "targetTag"              : "1.0.1",                        // Target Tag

    "copy": true
}
```

The API was tested and screenshot taken on with Artifactory EnterpriseX license 7.33.8 rev 73308900

Comment: The "repository" field is not needed in the JSON and is not mentioned in the documentation. The repository is already passed in the URL.